# why to use LUIS with QnA

Tags: bots, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I have a QnA with almost 200 questions. My clients are asking to add LUIS services in our bot. I tried to implement Bot with QnA and LUIS together but I am wondering what shall I put in the utterances? all the QnA questions?

these questions are really vivid and no pattern between them. In such case, how to make LUIS recognize the most matched question?

Please comment.

thanks,
Vivek

Comment: Could you name any reason or goal regarding "My clients are asking to add LUIS services in our bot"?

Comment: they want to group Q and A based on the topics. so shall I make individual intents for each topic and paste all questions for these intents as utternaces?

Comment: @VivekJain - If my answer isn't satisfactory, can you comment or update your question to explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you've designed your bot so that "QnAMaker question" is just one LUIS intent among multiple intents. If that's the case, just add as many QnA question utterances as you like so that LUIS will come to understand what a QnA question looks like as distinct from the other intents. It may take a lot of training and you should be prepared for low confidence scores, so just plan to accommodate that.

If you have multiple QnA knowledge bases each with their own LUIS intent, you may need to add every single question as an utterance to ensure that LUIS knows which specific knowledge base each question applies to. However, you can also write some failsafe code to account for situations where LUIS guesses the wrong knowledge base. It might look something like this:

```
[LuisIntent("KnowledgeBase2")]
public async Task KnowledgeBase2Handler(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    if (KnowledgeBaseContains(result.Query, knowledgeBase2))
    {
        // Answer the question with the correctly-selected knowledge base
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var kb in knowledgeBases)
        {
            if (KnowledgeBaseContains(result.Query, kb))
            {
                // Answer the question with the correct knowledge base
                // that LUIS didn't guess
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I already tried this way as you have suggested but with this way, I cannot tell if LUIS is really has a role more than a dispatcher. QnA is sometimes behaving dumbly for example questions like "A-sachnummern?" or "N-Sachnummern?" are the same for him and it returns the answer which appears first in the QnA base. Do you know how can I resolve this ?

Comment: It's true that LUIS can be somewhat redundant when also using QnA Maker, since messages are necessarily evaluated twice. And if QnA Maker is returning the same answer for two different questions then you may just have to train it more

Comment: @VivekJain Do you want to mark this answer as correct?

Comment: @KyleDelaney how can we do this in the Node.JS

Comment: @VivekJain - if/else blocks are the same in JavaScript as C#, and foreach is only slightly different in that you can just write `for` instead of `foreach`: https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-difference-between-foreach-and-for-in-992db038e4c2